# Sharing Google Cloud Project OAuth2 Client ID - Safe?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-oauth

I am currently working on a Chrome Extension, which has the OAuth2 Client ID of a Google Cloud Project in the manifest.json File. I want to make this Extension Open Source. However, I wonder if is it safe to publish the Client ID.

The OAuth2 Client ID is of type Chrome Extension and is Linked via ID of the Unpacked Extension.